# how to store values in javascript and compare them when needed

Tags: javascript, html, hashmap

I have the following values which need to be hard coded and compared in javascript

the values are :

```
SR = PlantWRShippingMail@shawinc.com
26 = Plant26ShippingMail@shawinc.com
29 = Plant29ShippingMail@shawinc.com
30 = Plant30ShippingMail@shawinc.com
34 = Plant34ShippingMail@shawinc.com
54 = Plant54ShippingMail@shawinc.com
41 = Plant41ShippingMail@shawinc.com
47 = Plant47ShippingMail@shawinc.com
DL = Plant.DL.Shipping.Mail@shawinc.com
37 = Plant37ShippingMail@shawinc.com
MU = PlantMUShippingMail@shawinc.com
UC = PlantUCShippingMail@shawinc.com
NB = plantnbshippingmail@shawinc.com
```

and so on

I have to compare the value with the existing value like

```
var plantNo=document.getElementById('plantNo').value;
if(plantNo=`anyonevaluefromAbove`){
    //than get the value of it.
}
```

How to do I do this in javascript.

Comment: Object in JS can do the job. e.g `o['key'] = 'value'`

Comment: What have you tried? This is as simple as looking up a value in an associative array.

Comment: Don't know who suggested to close but may i know the reason for doing so, So that in future we can avoid asking such kind of questions.

Comment: You have obviously not put a lot of effort into your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use JS Object

```
var obj = {
SR: "PlantWRShippingMail@shawinc.com", ...
}
```

then simply looking

```
if(obj[plantNo]) {
// obj[plantNo] is value 
}
```

is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an object to store the hard coded values as a map; first store all of the plants in an object:

```
var plants = {
  SR: "PlantWRShippingMail@shawinc.com",
  26: "Plant26ShippingMail@shawinc.com",
  29: "Plant29ShippingMail@shawinc.com",
  // and so on
  NB: "plantnbshippingmail@shawinc.com"
};
```

Then look up values from the object using:

```
var plantNo=document.getElementById('plantNo').value;
if(plants[plantNo]){
  alert(plants[plantNo]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store these values in a javascript object.

```
var someobj = {'SR' : 'PlantWRShippingMail@shawinc.com'
               // other keys
};

var plantNo=document.getElementById('plantNo').value;
if(someobj[plantNo]){
    alert(someobj[plantNo]); // than get the value of it.
}
```